# How can indents be preserved in liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm working on a jekyll project which requires me to create a code-snippet includable element. The code to include an element looks like this:

```
  {% include callouts/codeSnippet.html
       title="The title of the snippet"
       bodyText="'Lines of code', 'for(as many as you need) {', '    indented with spaces', '}' "
  %}
```

This is handled by the include file codeSnippet.html, which contains the following:

```
<div class="row codeSnippet">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <i class="fa fa-file-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <h1>{{ include.title }}</h1>
        {% assign rows = include.bodyText | split: ',' %}
        {% for row in rows %}
            <div class="snippetField">
                <span class="lineNumber">{{ forloop.index }}</span> {{ row | remove: "'" }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}  
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that when liquid receives the four spaces before 'indented with spaces' it removes them before displaying the output, so the output generated by Jekyll is this:

```
        <h1>The title of the snippet</h1>


            <div class="snippetField">
                <span class="lineNumber">1</span> Lines of code
            </div>

            <div class="snippetField">
                <span class="lineNumber">2</span>  for(as many as you need) {
            </div>

            <div class="snippetField">
                <span class="lineNumber">3</span>    indented with spaces
            </div>

            <div class="snippetField">
                <span class="lineNumber">4</span>  } 
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after writing this, I discovered the HTML `<pre></pre>` container, which supports preformatted text and seems to solve the problem.

More on the pre tag here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

TLDR: Jekyll / Liquid work fine, and it's just the general way that HTML works that requires the use of the Pre tag.